# My query, getting value from a textbox inside a subform, shows "small box"

Tags: sql, ms-access

> The overall scenario: Actually trying to implement an order entry
> system. A button on the main form opens 2nd form. In the 2nd form,
> there are some combo-boxes and list-boxes from which the user selects
> an item. Then pressing a button add that item with append query.
> The problem is, as soon as I click anywhere in the 2nd (child) form;
> the the id (autonumber) from parent vanishes(becomes null) for new
> entry in the 2nd form. (I have lately discovered this vanishing by
> using a text box to show current parent-id. Also found a solution,
> posting as an answer)

I am trying to get two values from a textbox and a combo box. In the query datasheet view, i checked that, one value is received correctly but the other value it shows a very small box (putting picture below)

[image: query shows very small box])

In this picture, "Expr2" field is showing small box. I used below statement to pull value from subform:

```
Expr2:[Forms]![customer_f]![products_add_subf].[Form]![customer_id]
```

And here is the code in sql-view:

```
INSERT INTO products_t ( product_name, customer_id )
SELECT [Forms]![customer_f]![products_add_subf].[Form]![item_combo] AS Expr1, [Forms]![customer_f]![products_add_subf].[Form]![customer_id] AS Expr2;
```

[image: query that shows small box as result]

What this small box mean and how to avoid it ? How to pull correct value instead of small box ?

Comment: Some sort of corruption? Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: It's the symbol for a non-printable character. You can try this in the Immediate Window: `? Asc([Forms]![customer_f]![products_add_subf].[Form]![customer_id])` to find out what it is, but that won't necessarily help to find the cause.

Comment: in the immediate window it shows correct value

Comment: Why are you even using SQL to save data from textboxes? Why not use BOUND form?

Comment: i will use same technique to add new record from combo box:::---> user will select item from a unbound listbox (or maybe combobox). And then add that item to new record.  Something like order entry system. I haven't learned vba yet, thats why using append query.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will prevent vanishing of parent-id from first form(parent); in the 2nd form (child).
Just disable "Allow Addition" in the 2nd form's property.
Steps:
Open the 2nd form in "design view" . Double Click at the upper left corner of the form to open its property sheet. Goto "data" tab. In the "Allow Addition" select "no".
Now your append query will be able to grab the parent id field. It will not vanish !